# Is there a JSR-330 equivalent of Spring's @Value annotation?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, jsr330

I'm trying to use JSR-330 annotations with Spring 3.

Is there a JSR-330 equivalent of Spring's `@Value` annotation for inserting property values? e.g. can I use `@Provider` in a way that will instruct Spring to inject a property value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked for usages of `@Value` in a project that is using `org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar`.  The annotation is referenced in two places here, `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and `QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver`.

In `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, the only JSR-330 annotation mentioned is `javax.inject.Inject`.

```
public AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor()
{
    this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add(Autowired.class);
    this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add(Value.class);
    ClassLoader cl = AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class.getClassLoader();
    try {
        this.autowiredAnnotationTypes.add(cl.loadClass("javax.inject.Inject"));
        this.logger.info("JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException localClassNotFoundException)
    {
    }
}
```

`QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver` makes no mention of JSR-330 annotations.